# calculate percentage of each key_fields in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data type with a key_field and a volume that show the value of each key_field.
for example:

| port | volume |
| --- | --- |
| 80 | 100000 |
| 443 | 200000 |
| 53 | 300000 |

It is easy to calculate volume percentage of each port with sql in one query.
for example :

```
select port , volume*100/ (select sum(volume) from  table) 
from table
```

or you can calculate this value with join.

My question is how to calculate this percentage with one query in elastic search ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for elastic to calculate the percentages you could use a percentile ranks query with a rank for each port.  The percentage values would be the difference between each of the results.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-rank-aggregation.html

The more typical approach would be to use a term aggregation and do the math using the doc_count numbers in the results.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html

This method will be much faster than your equivalent SQL search, on any dataset of significant size.

While SQL gives you a fair amount of flexibility in formatting the results, allowing you do something like this, Elastic is purely focused on bringing back the raw information at very high speed.